# How to send several files contained in a directory using expect?

Tags: expect

Hello I am writing the following script to automatically send several files using the ftp protocol, I decided to use expect to achieve this, I tried, the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
```

Defining variables:

```
set user myUser
set gate myGate
set password myPassword
```

Defining a token that changes every 3 minutes:

```
set token [lindex $argv 0]
```

Here is the second parameter that is the name of the file to send:

```
set file [lindex $argv 1]
set server myServer
set password2 myPassword2
spawn ftp ${gate}
expect "some lines of response:"
send "${user}\r"
expect "password:"
send "${password}${token}\r"
expect "ftp>"
send "user myServer\r"
expect "Password:"
send "myPassword2"
```

Changing me to the appropriate directory:

```
send "pwd\r"
send "cd myFolder\r"
expect "successfully changed."
```

here is where the problem appears:

```
send "put ${file}\r"
interact
```

I run it as follows:

```
expect.exe ftpScript myToken filesToSend/
```

Everything is ok until the part where it tries to send the directory with the files:

```
ftp> myFolder/
250 Directory successfully changed.
ftp> put filesToSend/
filesToSend/: not a plain file.
ftp>
```

My folder is located at the same level where is stored my script:

```
ls:

filesToSend ftpScript
```

If I do an ls to the directory called filesToSend it looks as follows:

```
$ ls
file1  file10  file11  file12  file2  file3  file4  file5  file6  file7  file8  file9
```

Thus I would like to appreciate any idea to achieve this and how to improve my code since recently I started to learn expect, thanks in advance for the help.

After an answer I copied the script into the same folder where are located the files to send and I tried:

```
send "mput ${file}\r"
```

but after to run it:

```
expect.exe ftpScript token file10  file11  file12
```

with that three files for testing, I only was able to send file10 succesfully, after a confirmation:

```
mput file10? y
200 PORT command successful [translated to PASV by DeleGate].
150 Ok to send data.
226 File receive OK.
```

I believe that is only sending one file since the way that I am using to get the parameters I only  have this line to get the parameters:

```
 set file [lindex $argv 1]
```

I am not very sure if I need to use here a list and this is the reason that causes that only one file sent, just is considering argv1 this script, Thanks for the support, I would like to receive suggestions to fix it.

Comment: You really don't need expect for this: there are plenty of scriptable FTP clients. If you like Tcl, use the [ftp package from tcllib](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/ftp/ftp.html). You can use [lftp](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/lftp.1.html). There will be ftp modules for just about any scripting language. I love expect, but it's often not the right tool for the job.

Comment: @glennjackman, Thanks for the support I heard good things about Tcl, some of my friend use it at work, the problem is that I do not how to start since it is a new language for me, I am going to try with expect for a moment and If it does not work I will begin to learn about Tcl, I really appreciate the support, thanks

Comment: Search for the "Tcl tutorial"  - really good starting point

Comment: @glennjackman, Thanks for the support, I will start there,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could solve your problem by using the command `mput` with a wildcard instead of `put`.

Edit your `expect` script to change the `put` line by the following :

```
send "mput ${file}\r"
```

Then invoke with :

```
expect ftpScript myToken filesToSend/*
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the support, however I got an issue, I put the lines that I got: 250 Directory successfully changed., ftp> mput filesToSend/file1, mput filesToSend/file1? y, 200 PORT command successful [translated to PASV by DeleGate].
553 Could not create file.

Comment: Are you sure you've got write permissions on the `myFolder` folder?

Comment: Maybe it's trying to create a `myFolder/filesToSend/filename1` file and fails because the `filesToSend` folder does not exists.

Comment: Hello thanks for the help, I verified the permissions but everything is ok at least in my computer I mean the folder that I want to send, I am thinking maybe that in the other side I mean in the server, maybe they do not allow the usage of mput but I am not sure,

Comment: If I perform an ls filesToSend/* at the level where I am working I got the following: $ ls filesToSend/*
filesToSend/file1   filesToSend/file11  filesToSend/file2  filesToSend/file4  filesToSend/file6  filesToSend/file8
filesToSend/file10  filesToSend/file12  filesToSend/file3  filesToSend/file5  filesToSend/file7  filesToSend/file9

Comment: Hello I created at the other side in the server a directory called: filesToSend/ surprisingly after this It worked ok for the first file1, after expect.exe ftpScript token filesToSend/*, I got: ftp> mput filesToSend/file1
mput filesToSend/file1? y
200 PORT command successful [translated to PASV by DeleGate].
150 Ok to send data.
226 File receive OK.
ftp> bye
221 Goodbye. although it worked just for 1 file,

Comment: `mput` asks for validation. I think you should either `interact` or `expect ? send y\r`

Comment: yes but That is not the main problem I realized that since I am using this line: set file [lindex $argv 1] to receive the file I am just taking the first argv 1 and I believe that due to this I cannot use * to send several files I tried to explain the situation in the question, thanks in advance for all the support,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125729/discussion-between-neo33-and-aaron).

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue as follows:

If we perform:

```
cd filesToSend
```

and then we modify the script as follows:

```
spawn ftp -i ${gate}
```

-i flag turns off the interactive mode which prompts for confirmation for every files.

Then we use:

```
send "mput *\r"
```

Finally we are able to send all the files without error to the destiny, running just:

```
expect.exe /myPath/ftpScript myToken
```

we receive all the files in the correct destiny:

```
file1  file10  file11  file12  file2  file3  file4  file5  file6  file7  file8  file9
```

Thanks for all the useful comments, after to research I decided to post my answer since maybe someone find this script useful to make their life easier, talking about to send multiple files using ftp,